# Limit inside and outside of probability

Tags: probability

For an infinite sequence $\{A_n\}$, is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) = P(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n)$? What are some examples or counterexamples?

What is the meaning of $\lim_{n \rightarrow A_n} P(A_n)$ if it is not equal?  I cannot understand what the LHS means.

Comment: $\lim A_n$ does not always exist.

Comment: Take $A_{2n}=\Omega$ and $A_{2n-1}=\phi$ for $n \in\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

Comment: For example for $A_n=[0,0.5]$ for n even and $A_n=[0.5,1]$ else, RHS doesn’t exist. On the other hand if you have the inclusion $A_i \subset A_i$ for $i<j$, then RHS exist and equals LHS. The same holds if the inclusion holds for all $i>j$, both can be proven by monotone convergence

Comment: Sorry, RHS only exists  if $lim A_n$ is measurable!